# apache2 append www to https url

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, rewritecond

I have an apache2 webserver in AWS using bitnami. In my `bitnami.conf` file I need to rewrite all URLs to

```
https://www.example.com
```

I am able to redirect the following correctly

```
mydomain.com
http://example.com
www.example.com
```

But when the url is `https://example.com` it does not redirect to `https://www.example.com.`

my configuration is

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
      DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
      RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?example.com$ [NC]
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
      RewriteRule .? http://www.%example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
      RewriteRule /smecweb/(.*) /$1 [R=301]
      RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

I tried to do something similar in  `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`, but reverted it.

Can someone point out what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This virtualhost only listens on port 80. It will never be accessed with https. You need to add this to your :443 VirtualHost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RewriteCond`  and `RewriteRule` you are using doesn't sound right. 
What's the defined server name?

You can try this config:

```
Servername www.example.com
Serveralias  example.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [L,R=301,QSA,NE]
```